# Los siguientes prefijos siguen siendo necesarios en CSS3?

Tags: css, css3

estoy leyendo un libro de html5,css3 y javascript editado en el año 2012 y tengo una duda sobre el uso de los siguientes prefijos:

•-moz- para Firefox.

• -webkit- para Safari y Chrome.

• -o- para Opera.

• -khtml- para Konqueror.

• -ms- para Internet Explorer.

• -chrome- específico para Google Chrome.

**En el libro aclara:**

> **IMPORTANTE:** En este momento las nuevas incorporaciones de CSS3 están siendo
> implementadas en las últimas versiones de los navegadores más populares, pero
> algunas de ellas se encuentran aún en estado experimental. Por esta razón, estos
> nuevos estilos deberán ser precedidos por prefijos tales como –moz- o -webkitpara ser efectivamente interpretados. Analizaremos este importante asunto más
> adelante.

**Ejemplo de codigo .css:**

```
div {
 width: 100px;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;

 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Lo que quiero saber:**

Han pasado 8 años desde la publicación del libro y no sé si siguen siendo obligatorios o se a optimizado con otro estándar, ¿podría sacarme de dudas?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo :)

Comment: Podrias indicamre donde encontrar un hilo que me explique la actualidad de los usos en estos prefijos? gracias

Comment: perdona mi ignorancia pero no se donde encontrar esta funcion dentro de esta web. Como dices reportes hay, antes de publicar he observado la de posibles temas parecidos y no encontre la respuesta a tal duda.

Si dispones del link donde comprovar esta informacion te lo agradezco.

Comment: Wow! se me escapo de la vista el link! MUCHAS GRACIAS POR LA PAGINA WEB!!!!

Comment: Pues ya esta, sinceramente respondiste mi duda! esta web es una gran herramienta :D!!!


Muchas gracias por la colaboracion ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay básicamente dos problemas que obligan a usar lo que se conoce como [*vendor prefix*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

### A. La compatibilidad entre versiones

Un alto porcentaje del código de CSS3 es soportado en la mayoría de navegadores modernos. Ahora bien, en la comunidad de programadores hay debate incluso sobre qué navegadores (y a partir de qué versiones) se pueden considerar *modernos*.

Pero esa compatibilidad es a partir de una determinada versión del navegador. Por lo tanto, deberás seguir poniendo en tu código los fragmentos relativos al *vendor prefix*, porque cualquier usuario de tu página puede estar usando una versión de navegador no compatible con ese selector o función CSS.

Existe un sitio llamado [`caniuse.com`](https://caniuse.com/)  donde puedes verificar la compatibilidad por navegadores y versiones de un determinado selector o propiedad. Si estás escribiendo una biblioteca, framework o simplemente para el CSS de tu sitio web, deberás consultar en ese sitio la compatibilidad, para decidir de qué forma escribir el código CSS de esas nuevas funciones.

En `canisue.com` sólo tienes que escribir en el cuadro superior la propiedad que quieres verificar, la pantalla se actualiza y verás toda la información que se ofrece. Veamos una imagen con algunas explicaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basándonos en dos casos podremos comprender que es casi imposible librarse (por completo) de usar los *vendor prefix*.

1. En [el caso de `border-box`](https://caniuse.com/#search=border-box), es compatible con el `98.24%` de los navegadores (nº 3 en la imagen). Pero, si observas en algunos recuadros verdes, verás dentro de ellos unos pequeños **recuadros amarillos**. Si pones el puntero sobre cualquiera de ellos verás de qué se trata:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

   Se lee claramente: *Supported with prefix `-webkit-`*. Significa que para hacer funcionar `border-box` en esas versiones (las que tienen el recuadro pequeño amarillo), tienes que usar el prefijo `-webkit-` en el código CSS.
2. En el caso de los [efectos de filtro](https://caniuse.com/) la cosa cambia, porque **hay incompatibilidades en casi todos los navegadores**, y dicha incomptibilidad se resuelve en algunos casos aplicando solamente `webkit` y en otros (todos los de rojo) tendrás que asegurar compatibilidad mediante código propio para cada navegador usando el *vendor prefix*  propio de ese navegador.

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### B. La variedad de navegadores y la incapacidad para ponerse de acuerdo

Este fue un gran problema (sobre todo en el pasado) que obligaba a seguir usando los prefijos. Hoy día los desarrolladores de cada navegador han empezado a ponerse de acuerdo. Por eso puedes ver que en las recientes versiones de navegadores, el prefijo `webkit` se va universalizando, de modo que para la compatibilidad con la mayoría de navegadores, es suficiente con usar dicho prefijo.